# After moving inline css into stylesheet, works in design view but not while running

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, stylesheet

I'm trying to move some css out of my master page into a stylesheet.  Basically, what I did:

- Copy/Pasted inline css into new stylesheet
- Referenced the stylesheet from the master page

After doing this, the design view continued to display as expected (I saw my styles go away when I took the css out of the master page, but then they returned after I added the reference to the new stylesheet I put them in, as expected).  However when I run the project and it opens up in Firefox it acts like the styles are gone.  It seems odd to me that it would work in the design view but not in the web browser.

I am thinking this is just because of something really simple that I am unaware of b/c I'm new to making websites.

Here is the current code for the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
    <link href="~/Styles/SiteMaster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
    <link href="~/Styles/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/ddaccordion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/menuInit.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table class="mainTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="headerCell" colspan="2" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="menuCell">
                <div class="urbangreymenu">
                    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></h3>
                    <%--<ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/category/C1/">Horizontal CSS Menus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/category/C2/">Vertical CSS Menus</a></li>
                    </ul>--%>

                    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="PostItem.aspx">Post Items</a></h3>
                   <%-- <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/cutpastejava.shtml" >Free JavaScripts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/">JavaScript tutorials</a></li>
                    </ul>--%>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="contentCell">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="footerCell" colspan="2" />
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for SiteMaster.css:

```
.mainTable
{
    width: 100%;
}
.menuCell
{
    width: 218px;
    height: 157px;
}
.headerCell
{
    height: 63px;
}
.footerCell
{
    height: 77px;
}
.contentCell
{
    height: 157px;
}
```

Comment: View the source in Firefox and see where if the stylesheet is loading and if not, where the link is pointing to.

Comment: Relevant Firefox source: <link href="Styles/SiteMaster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design time is misleading you. If your site structure is like that:

```
content
   site.css
master
   site.master
pages
   store
      mypage.aspx
   admin
      tools
         adminpage.aspx
```

A link to the css could look like this in the master page: `../content/site.css` and this link looks correct and VS designer has no problem finding the css in design time. However, in runtime the master page doesn't run alone but with a content page, and the link to the css page is sent as is to the client.
You might think that `../../content/site.css` can work, however this is correct just for `mypage.aspx` but not for `adminpage.aspx`.

The solution for that is to let the server help you:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/site.css" runat="server" />
```

This way you always get the right link no matter what is the page folder.

To overcome css browser cache, add a version to the link like `File.css?version=1` and increment it on any change, or use hash versioning like in here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203288/Automatic-JS-CSS-versioning-to-update-browser-cach

Comment: I put what the Firefox source code looks in my previous comment because that's what I was asked for, but in the actual Site.master page it looks like this: <link href="~/Styles/SiteMaster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Added runat="server", but doesn't seem to change anything :/.  I modeled my code after the style sheet link that was generated as part of the project template which looks like this: <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Checkout the source I just added to my post and see if you find some glaringly obvious error that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Just noticed using FireBug that in SiteMaster.css it's still using names like .style3, .style4, etc. instead of the names I changed them to.  I think that's the problem, but not sure why it's doing this.

Comment: I don't see any error in your code. I tried my code now and any link like "~/folder/file.css" is replaced by "../../folder/file.css" to exactly the correct path, if I add runat="server". Does it happen only in FireFox?

Comment: I think you have a browser cache problem also. Add dummy query string to your links like: `file.css?version=1`

Comment: Okay, I just copied SiteMaster.css to a new file called MasterPage.css and changed the reference to look to this file and it works perfect now.  I wonder why Visual Studio wasn't picking up these changes when running?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right about the cache problem.  What can I do about that?

Comment: Add the dummy query string. Look in my comment above.

Comment: Okay, but then will that particular variation be cached and then I run into the same problem next time I make a change or does that keep it from ever caching?

Comment: So change the version again `file.css?version=2` each time you change the css. Look here a better automatic solution. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203288/Automatic-JS-CSS-versioning-to-update-browser-cach

Comment: Thanks!  You might add that to your answer if you don't mind.